# Android webview get current url and check if it contains a string

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

The previous post is from here [android studio webview get data and onfinish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392589/android-studio-webview-get-data-and-onfinish/42392837#42392837) . I actually cannot get what I want from those answers. Maybe I should ask it more clearly. I actually used webview to load a content page. Then inside the content page, there are some links which are also local html created by myself. So the flow is like

android activity -> webview -> content page -> game page.

I actually want to retrieve a local variable `marks` in the game page. So I created a `exit` button, which is used to close the page and back to the android activity as well as carry the `marks` back to the android activity.

So I searched some information myself, and found that `window.close()` doesn't work. So I change the current URL to indicate that the exit button is clicked. And then extract the `marks` from the URL and store it in the android activity. But it doesn't work with my codes below, I think it is probably because of the method is used, when I am in the content page. I hope someone could help to do this, as I really cannot find the problem. I have edited the codes as below:

My activity in android:

```
private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    try {            
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

        @Override 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
           if (url.contains("?marks=")){
             finish();}  // close activity
           else{
             view.loadUrl(url);}

           return true; 
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(webview);
}
```

My exit button is a div:

```
<div class="exit" onclick="finish()">Exit</div>
```

I am going to use the `finish()` function to return the variable and close the webpage back to the activity in android.

```
function finish() {
  document.location.href= window.location.href +"?marks=" + marks;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think question is solved, as `webview.loadUrl` should be placed at the end.
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
       if (url.contains("?marks=")){
         finish();}  // close activity
       else{
         view.loadUrl(url);}

       return true; 
    });

    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```